# Multiplication of the values of two textboxes and displaying result in the third textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am developing an inventory system in which i fetch the data from database through textbox1 and the data compatible to the entry in textbox1 appears in textbox8 and textbox10 which are integers. Now i want to multiply textbox8 and textbox10 and the result should be display into textbox7 when the integers appears in textbox8 and textbox10.

i am using this piece of code for multiplication of two textboxes and result in the third text box does not appear:

```
private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Int32 val1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text);
            Int32 val2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
            Int32 val3 = val1 * val2;
            textBox7.Text = val3.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: When you debug this, what are the values of `val1`, `val2`, and `val3`?  Also, to help you get a handle on your code, you might want to use more meaningful names than `textBox7, `textBox8`, and `textBox10`, `val1`, `val2`, and so on...

Comment: What the purpose of this?. You are changing the value of TextBox7 inside the event TextBox7_TextChanged.

Comment: val1 and val2 can be any value from the database.
i want to display the result of val3 in textbox7.text

ok sir i will take care next time and provide meaningful names.

Comment: @Steve...to display the result automatically without the use of any button or clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned the event to the wrong control and you're not checking for valid input. You can use `int.TryParse` to look for valid, numerical input.

```
        private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Multiply();
        }

        private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Multiply();
        }

        public void Multiply()
        {
            int a, b;

            bool isAValid = int.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out a);
            bool isBValid = int.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out b);

            if (isAValid && isBValid)
                textBox7.Text = (a * b).ToString();

            else
                textBox7.Text = "Invalid input";
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using the wrong textbox for your TextChanged event. Your textboxes 8 and 10 are changing but you have attached the shown code to textbox7.

```
public MyForm : Form {
    public MyForm(){
        InitializeComponents();
        // Here you define what TextBoxes should react on user input
        textBox8.TextChanged += TextChanged;
        textBox10.TextChanged += TextChanged;
    }

    private void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int val1;
        int val2;

        if (!int.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out val1) || !int.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out val2))
            return;

        Int32 val3 = val1 * val2;
        // Here you define what TextBox should show the multiplication result
        textBox7.Text = val3.ToString();

    }
}
```

And finally remove the code inside `textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: so which textbox i should use for it?

Comment: You should attach the TextChanged event on textbox8 and textbox10, because these two are expected to change.

Comment: can you please make some changes in my code or type an example?
i am not getting it becuase i want to print the result in textbox7

Comment: Your snippet is not showing that part that should be changed. You are usually adding event handlers through the Visual Studio Designer. What you have to understand is the TextChanged event. This event is fired when the user types something into the TextBox (textbox8+10). It has nothing to do with where you want to write your result (textbox7).

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting any compile or bug problems? You need to give your controls meaningful names to better differentiate these controls. Double check that you are referencing your controls properly. In any case, your code should work. My code below catches a failure to convert to int32 below.

```
    try
    {
        textBox7.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text)).ToString();
    }
    catch (System.FormatException)
    { }
```

Comment: maybe you are getting the error because of textbox10 because the "t" in .Text should be capital.

Comment: Capitalized the 't'. You should use the answer above. I didn't notice you were using the wrong event. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

private void textBox7_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Int32 val1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text);
        Int32 val2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
        Int32 val3 = val1 * val2;
        textBox7.Text = Convert.ToString(val3);

    }
```